# NAT loopback/reflection on Zyxel P-661HW-D1 doesn't work

Tags: router, nat, port-forwarding, zyxel

I have a Zyxel P-661HW-D1 modem/router with several port forwards that works on the WAN interface. I'd like to make them work for the LAN interface as well, like I'm used to.
I updated the firmware to the last version I found (V3.40(AHQ.4) | 07/08/2009) and I activated the nat loopback option from the command line, that should enable the desired behaviour.
The loopback seems to be active after rebooting the router as well, as I can get this response from the CLI:

```
ras> ip nat loopback
NAT loopback: on
ras>
```

Still, the port forwards don't work inside the LAN.
E.g. I have a server on `192.168.1.200:5000` that I can't reach by `192.168.1.1:5000` (router's LAN ip) nor by `<WAN IP>:5000`.
Such server is only reachable by `<WAN IP>:5000` from a machine that is outside the LAN.

Comment: Do you have more than one router in your network?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz no, and with my old router (I switched to this one recently) it worked fine